# Creating a job portal system

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I want to create a job system with the following workflow:

1. Administrator can add the jobs.
2. A page for job listings.
3. On detail job there should a link of apply for this job.
4. The form will contain the fields and upload application form.
5. **The back end must display the number of application received for respective job.**
6. On click on number of application received for respective job the see the list of Application received list for particular job category.

I have tried it with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

Created a view for job listing and use webform for apply form. But **what should I do with the trackers in point 5?**

Answer (score 4):

I would implement this in the following manner:

1. Two content types: Job opening & Job application
2. Job openings to have fields like : Job description, current CTC, expected CTC, etc.
3. Job application to have fields like : Cover letter, experience, resume (file upload), etc.
4. **Important**: In job application content type, add an entityreference field that refers to Job openings.
5. Give permission to company user to create job opening; and normal user to create job application.

With this architecture, you should easily be able to build the views as entityreference module provides two very powerful relationships:

1. Entity reference: Referenced entity (Job opening)
2. Entity reference: Referencing entity (Job application)

Comment: thank a lot for your solution. But how to display the number of application received for respective job.

Comment: @KadambiniDas I am afraid, I don't have much time to write down the complete answer. Just to give you pointer, and I have already mentioned this in the answer, you have to use views to build this and the relationships provided by entityreference module. I will try to expand on the answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Webform module, so this is just a hypothetical / shot in the dark suggestion (assuming somehow your webform links with your Job opening node).

Add a Numeric field to your Job Opening content type.

With [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) you can react when a Webform is submitted.
So when webform is submitted, Add action of set a data value, you can add an offset of +1 to your numeric field. (you may need to click on <kbd>Switch to something input mode</kbd> to get the offset option)

The tricky part in the rule would be linking your webform with the correct job posting node. If you can figure out this part, you're golden.

Lastly, you would just add the numeric field to your view.

> **BONUS**: You could use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to hide
>   your numeric field from node edit view.